# Can we make use of php.ini variables in other configurations

Tags: config, php, log4php

Can we make use of php.ini variables in other configuration files like log4php configuration file?

In log4php I am using LoggerAppenderRollingFile appender and I have used log file location as /var/www/MyProject/logs/log.text, But I want to externalize the project root ( /var/www/MyProject ) instead of hardcoding and I thought of having it in php.ini.

Is it possible to do it using php.ini, or can you suggest me a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a great idea to put application specific configurations in php.ini, but regardless if you use php.ini or another ini file you can use [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) or [parse_ini_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) for loading data from it.